# Can't use lib component in Nx Jest Angular test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, nrwl-nx

I have an Nx monorepo. In an app, I am using a component from a lib (project). It can be served or built without issues. When testing this app however I am getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstCreatePass' of null

```
  at providersResolver (../../../packages/core/src/render3/di_setup.ts:47:13)
  at Object.definition.providersResolver (../../../packages/core/src/render3/features/providers_feature.ts:48:18)
  at resolveDirectives (../packages/core/src/render3/instructions/shared.ts:1180:40)
  at elementStartFirstCreatePass (../packages/core/src/render3/instructions/element.ts:40:7)
  at ɵɵelementStart (../packages/core/src/render3/instructions/element.ts:87:7)
  at ɵɵelement (../packages/core/src/render3/instructions/element.ts:180:3)
  at MyAppComponent_div_0_div_78_Template (../../ng:/MyAppComponent.js:220:5)
```

I get this error in MyAppComponent if I try to use in the template of MyAppComponent a component from a lib (project). It is an empty component (only a div). I tried to debug it and I can see the template of MyLibComponent in Scripts ng://

I know it is not possible to pinpoint the error from the information that I have given. I am looking for suggestions on what to check and I will consider an answer as accepted if it leads me to the solution.

**what follows is a long explanation of my debugging efforts:**

Of course, the MyLibComponent module is included in the TestBed. The error doesn't occur on TestBed({...}).compileComponents(), but on TestBed.CreateComponent(MyAppComponent).

If I add the import to the index.ts of the lib I can get it to work on TestBed.createComponent:

export * from './lib/ui.module';
export {MyLibComponent} from './lib/compositions/my-lib.component'
And running nx without cache: nx test my-app --skip-nx-cache

But then I get the same error on fixture.detectChanges(). MyLibComponent is already exported in UiModule.

I am also attaching my spec:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            MyLibModule,
            UtilModule,
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            SharedModule,
            DirectivesModule,
            PipesModule,
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
                [
                    { path: "", component: MyAppComponent },
                    { path: "**", redirectTo: "" },
                ]
            ),
            TranslateModule.forRoot(),
            InputSwitchModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            AutoCompleteModule,
            CalendarModule,
            ButtonModule,
            ProgressBarModule
        ],
        declarations: [MyAppComponent ],
        providers: [
            ComponentOutlet,
            {   
                provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
                    snapshot: { paramMap: {
                        get: jest.fn() 
                        } }
                }
            },
            {
                provide: ToastService,
                useClass: SpyToastServiceSpy
            },
            provideMockStore(),
            provideMockActions(() => actions$)
        ],
        schemas: [
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
    
    
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyAppComponent);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @DJBurb this is my spec, would you find something else useful?

Comment: Can you post MyAppComponent.ts (or js)?

Comment: @DJBurb I commented all code out in the MyAppComponent so that only the part of using the MyLibComponent in the template remained